# Jersey Client: adding Cookies does not change Builder

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

My first implementation using the Jersey client code with cookies does not successfully maintain session to next call. What is suspicious to me is that the method

```
Builder javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder.cookie(String s, String s1)
```

does not return a different instance of the builder. Shouldn't it?  Either way, my login request is denied with message "Your session expired due to inactivity.", which seems to imply to me that the request isn't arriving with the same session id as previous.

See anything wrong with this code? The culprit in question is method #applyCookies(Builder) which does not return anything different after the cookies have been set.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.filter.HttpBasicAuthFilter;

/**
 * A JAX-RS <a href="https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/" /> connector that uses
 * Jersey <a href="https://jersey.java.net"/> as the API to create a client that
 * will connect to a remote REST service.
 */
public class JerseyConnector extends WebServiceConnector
{
    /** Debug logger. */
    protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JerseyConnector.class);

    /**
     * Simple test execution method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws MessageException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessageException
    {
        JerseyConnector conn = new JerseyConnector();
        conn.setProviderURL("http://somehost.somewhere.com:7203/rest");
        conn.open();
        String sessConf = (String)conn.send("initiateSession");
        HashMap<String,String> content = new HashMap<String,String>(3);
        content.put("sessionConfirmation", sessConf);
        content.put("password", "password");
        content.put("login", "joe");
        String body = JSONMapFormatter.toJSON(content);
        String loginResponse = (String)conn.send(new RESTRequest("login", body, HttpMethod.POST));
        System.out.println(loginResponse);
    }

    protected WebTarget webTarget;
    protected Map<String,Cookie> cookies;

    /**
     * Calls the {@link #webTarget} and provides the {@link String} response.
     * The request method defaults to {@link HttpMethod#GET}.
     * <p>
     * If the <code>message</code> is a {@link String}, it is assumed to be the
     * suffix URI to append to the provider URL of the {@link #webTarget},
     * unless the string begins with a "{", in which case it is assumed to be
     * the JSON request body to send.
     * <p>
     * If the <code>message</code> is a {@link RESTRequest}, the path, body and
     * HTTP method will be determined from that.
     * <p>
     * Otherwise, the <code>toString()</code> version of the message will be
     * sent as the body of the message.
     * 
     * @see WebTarget#path(String)
     * @see WebTarget#request()
     * @see #getProviderURL()
     * @see oracle.retail.stores.commext.connector.webservice.WebServiceConnector#send(java.io.Serializable)
     */
    @Override
    protected Serializable send(Serializable message) throws MessageException
    {
        RESTRequest request = null;

        // determine path and body content if any
        if (message instanceof RESTRequest)
        {
            request = (RESTRequest)message;
        }
        else
        {
            request = new RESTRequest();
            String messageString = message.toString();
            if (messageString.startsWith("{"))
            {
                request.body = (String)message;
            }
            else
            {
                request.path = (String)message;
            }
        }

        // send request, get response
        Response response = sendRequest(webTarget, request);

        logger.debug("Response received.");

        // remember cookies that came in the response
        rememberCookies(response);

        // return response as a string
        return response.readEntity(String.class);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see oracle.retail.stores.commext.connector.webservice.WebServiceConnector#openConnector()
     */
    @Override
    protected void openConnector() throws MessageException
    {
        super.openConnector();

        // create a client
        logger.debug("Creating new client.");
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        // register the auth creds
        if (!Util.isEmpty(getUserName()))
        {
            logger.debug("Registering user credentials with client.");
            client.register(new HttpBasicAuthFilter(getUserName(), getPassword()));
        }
        else
        {
            logger.info("No credentials specified for \"" + getName() + "\".");            
        }

        // open the target url
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            logger.debug("Creating webTarget with \"" + getProviderURL() + "\".");
        }
        webTarget = client.target(getProviderURL());

        // construct a new cookie map
        cookies = new HashMap<String,Cookie>(3);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the response after invoking the specified request on the specified
     * target.
     *
     * @param target
     * @param request
     * @return 
     */
    protected Response sendRequest(WebTarget target, RESTRequest request)
    {
        // retarget destination
        if (request.path != null)
        {
            target = target.path(request.path);
        }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            logger.debug("Making service request " + request);
        }

        // build request
        Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        // apply cookies
        builder = applyCookies(builder);

        // call webservice and return response as a string
        if (HttpMethod.POST.equals(request.httpMethod))
        {
            return builder.post(Entity.entity(request.body, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        }
        else if (HttpMethod.PUT.equals(request.httpMethod))
        {
            return builder.put(Entity.entity(request.body, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        }
        else if (HttpMethod.DELETE.equals(request.httpMethod))
        {
            return target.request(request.body).delete();
        }

        // default to HttpMethod.GET
        return target.request(request.body).get();
    }

    /**
     * Apply all the cookies in the cookies map onto the request builder.
     *
     * @param builder
     * @return the cookied builder
     */
    private Builder applyCookies(Builder builder)
    {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            logger.debug("Applying " + cookies.size() + " cookies: " + cookies);
        }
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies.values())
        {
            builder = builder.cookie(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue());
        }
        return builder;
    }

    /**
     * Put all the cookies from the response into the map of cookies being
     * remembered.
     *
     * @param response
     */
    private void rememberCookies(Response response)
    {
        Map<String,NewCookie> newCookies = response.getCookies();
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            logger.debug("Remembering " + newCookies.size() + " cookies: " + newCookies);
        }
        cookies.putAll(newCookies);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Request parameters that can be sent to this connector in order to specify
     * the path (URL sub-sequence) and body (contents) of the request message to
     * send.
     */
    public static class RESTRequest implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5675990073393175886L;

        private String path;
        private String body;
        private String httpMethod;

        /**
         * Internal constructor
         */
        private RESTRequest()
        {
        }

        /**
         * @param path
         * @param body
         */
        public RESTRequest(String path, String body)
        {
            this.path = path;
            this.body = body;
        }

        /**
         * @param path
         * @param body
         * @param httpMethod see values at {@link javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod}
         */
        public RESTRequest(String path, String body, String httpMethod)
        {
            this.path = path;
            this.body = body;
            this.httpMethod = httpMethod;
        }

        /**
         * @return the path
         */
        public String getPath()
        {
            return path;
        }

        /**
         * @return the body
         */
        public String getBody()
        {
            return body;
        }

        /**
         * @return the httpMethod
         * @see javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod
         */
        public String getHttpMethod()
        {
            return httpMethod;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
         */
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "RESTRequest[" + httpMethod + ", " + path + ", with body=" + body + "]";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Was that with 'Form' authentication method or BASIC?

Answer (score 0):

The defect was in the bottom of the #sendRequest() method. It was ignoring the Builder object returned and re-using the WebTarget to create a new request (which creates a new builder. The last three lines of code in that method should have been:

```
        return builder.buildDelete().invoke();
    }

    // default to HttpMethod.GET
    return builder.buildGet().invoke();
```